# remove matching character of string 2 from string 1 in java here i'm getting the unexpected output?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Here i have my code where it prints unique characters from both strings and eliminates duplicates but i need the out put in such a way that eg:String 1="google out" and String 2="stack overflow" required output is String3="googlestackvrfw" i.e.,if any character of string2 matches with string 1 removes those and print result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String firstString = "google out"; // String(s) not String arrays
    String secondString = "stack overflow";
    // output cannot be larger then the sum of the inputs.
    char[] out = new char[firstString.length() + secondString.length()];
    int index = 0;
    // Add all unique chars from firstString
    for (char c : firstString.toCharArray()) {
        if (!contains(out, index, c)) {
            out[index++] = c;
        }
    }
    // Add all unique chars from secondString
    for (char c : secondString.toCharArray()) {
        if (!contains(out, index, c)) {
            out[index++] = c;
        }
    }
    // Create a correctly sized output array.
    char[] s = new char[index];
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        s[i] = out[i];
    }
    // Just print it.
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
}

public static boolean contains(char[] in, int index, char t) {
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (in[i] == t) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}
for this i'm getting out is:`[g, o, l, e,  , u, t, s, a, c, k, v, r, f, w]`but expected is:`String3="googlestackvrfw"` because in string 2[o,e,l] is already present in string one so i removed it.

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. From your description (removing duplicates), it seems like your code is working correctly. How do you arrive at "googlestackvrfw"?

Comment: @lc. I think the idea was you add one string to the other character by character except for the characters that already exist in the original string and/or the string you're currently working on

Comment: presently for this code logic is :if any character appears more than ones in both string excluding those characters and printing remaining as output.but Now i need the logic that if any character from second string matches with string 1 exclude that and remaining characters from of String 1 and string 2 has to print

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That is not a duplicate as the required output is completely different, and thus the algorithm would be completely different. There's something more going on than just removing duplicate alphabet characters straight up...