# Unexpected output while comparing strings and printing remaining characters in java?

Tags: java, string

Here I have 2 strings

```
String first = "stack overflow";
String second = "java programming";
```

from that I need output as:

```
stck eflow j prgmming
```

i.e., take character from first string and compare with remaining all character in second string, if present remove it. Here is my code giving some unexpected result:

```
String first = "stack overflow";
String second = "java programming";
for (int i = 0; i < first.length(); i++) {
    out.println("char position :" + first.charAt(i));
    for (int j = 0; j < second.length(); j++) {                    
        if (first.charAt(i) == second.charAt(j)) {
            first = first.substring(0, i) + first.substring(i + 1);
            second = second.substring(0, j) + second.substring(j + 1);
        }
    }
}
out.println(first+second);
```

Comment: Please [clarify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783710/how-to-remove-duplicate-alphabets-from-two-strings-in-java-without-any-builtin-f) your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796173/remove-matching-character-of-string-2-from-string-1-in-java-here-im-getting-the). Also, you seem to be confused - Java Strings are immutable Objects. Maybe you need a `StringBuilder`. Please describe your requirements completely.

Comment: This is the third question of this type I've seen in the last hour or so... With similar strings too. Coincidence, or am I missing something?

Comment: Here i'm getting output is:stckveflowjvapgramming but expected output is:stck eflow j prgmming. i.e.,from first String s is present at first characters search in second string if present exclude it like wise all elements need to print.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: @user3580294 same homework assignment

Comment: I suspect the not expected behavior is he is modifying the string and shifting all the characters over but still incrementing i and therefore skipping over characters.

Comment: when you modify `first`, the value of `first.length()` will not be re-evaluated.

Comment: @Razs Apps,could you please tell me where to modify the code

Comment: I think you'd find it more educational if you went through with a debugger and figured out where the code stops working as you expected...

Comment: @ThazAhammad It depends. Is this a homework assignment?  I don't want to give you the answer. I think my comment helped point you in the right direction of where to look.  You are directly modifying first and second string while attempting to read it.  That can be problematic.

Comment: @Razs Apps,I'm new to programming so that i'm taking help.

Comment: If you're new to programming, one of the things you should *definitely* learn is how to use a debugger. It's an incredibly useful and important skill for a programmer, and would let you solve both this situation and many others that you come across.

Comment: @ThazAhammad I answered your question.  I tried to make it as a psuedo tutorial for development.  You might also want to look to coursera.org and sign up for classes if you want to improve some of your programming skills for free.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the letters in each word first and from there I would print the statement.  Since you said the requirement is to print it and not return a value that's what I'll do.  If this is incorrect you can build the string the same way I print it and return it.  I'm going to try and make this more of a tutorial than an answer for you given our comment discussion.

The code makes the following assumptions: 
Only spaces are valid characters between both strings.
Both words are all in the same case.

```
//Getting the letters up front could allow us to improve 
//the efficiency of this algorithm to O(n) from your O(n^2) solution
private Set<Character> getLetters(String word) {
   HashSet<Character> letters= new HashSet<Character>();
   for (char c: word.toCharArray()) {
      //your output prints spaces so I'll skip them
      if (c != ' ')
         letters.add(c);
   }
   return letters;
}

//Breaking out duplicate code into methods is good for code reuse
//This method will print any character not in the Set provided
private void printUnmatchedCharacters(String word, Set<Character> letters) {
   for (char c: word.toCharArray()) {
       //Since this is actually a HashSet contains is fast at O(1)
       if(!letters.contains(c))
          System.out.print(c);
   }
}

public void printResults(String first, String second) {
   printUnmatchedCharacters(first, getLetters(second));
   //You have a space between your words
   System.out.print(' ');
   printUnmatchedCharacters(second, getLetters(first));
}
```

While the above code is longer it is more efficient and broken down into smaller chunks.  It is a bit easier to debug if an issue should arise and you could unit test it easier.  Since you are new to programming I was hoping this answer would help teach you some other things besides the question you were looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can use StringBuffer together with the String. Removing the the necessary chars from StringBuffer object instead of the String object.

```
    String first = "stack overflow";
    String second = "java programming";
    StringBuffer firstBuffer = new StringBuffer(first);
    StringBuffer secondBuffer = new StringBuffer(second);
    for (int i = 0; i < first.length(); i++) {
        out.println("char position :" + first.charAt(i));
        for (int j = 0; j < second.length(); j++) {                    
            if (first.charAt(i) == second.charAt(j)) {
                firstBuffer.deleteCharAt(i);
                secondBuffer.deleteCharAt(j);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(firstBuffer.toString()+secondBuffer.toString());
```

Comment: Throws `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` (and I'm pretty sure it needs quite a few changes to work) - please don't post untested code.

Comment: @Elvermg,showing error index out of bound exception

Comment: Then point he's trying to illustrate is that you can't operate on Strings like that in Java.  They are immutable.  Store a copy of the string you want modified in a String buffer ( or string builder ), modify that buffer or builder, and output that after iterating through the loop.  Even then though, you would still run into the situation where you are now changing the parameters of the loop, so may want to pop into a different loop all together based on your first iteration.